# Display database data into a table layout or into textviews

Tags: sql, android, database, textview

Hey guys, Im nuew to anddroid but struggling with databases.

How would i retrieve data from my database and put it into a table or textview

Comment: I have got a table working now buy im lookog to be able to put state into specific textfield of my choice. Own custom layout basically.

Answer (score 0):

You use Cursor and SQLite driver.

If you are struggling, then start doing the tutorials provided by google, particularly you might want to look at [notepad](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftutorials%2Fnotepad%2Findex.html&ei=Oc77TN3bLcPlrAe9hImpCA&usg=AFQjCNEhsW2ZFb-lSTgjhX3s3q4QWNHRDw&sig2=LxDoictNZRqFdj_muc2vuQ) tutorial. Start simple.

Comment: i can display data into a table but it only puts it into one big row. I dont know how i would put each database row in a seperate table row

Comment: What view do you use to present your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLiteOpenHelper. It provides getReadableDatabase() and getWritableDatabase() .these returns SQLiteDatabase.